# Showing explicitly that a function must be 0 if its integral with a test function is

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I'm self studying some functional analysis and came across this exercise that asks me to show that if $\int_\Omega fv=0$ then $f=0$ for every test function $v$. My question is- isn't this statement just trivially true since $v$ can be literally any test function? Is there a mathematically proper way to show it?

Comment: Probably you meant if, for every test function $v$, $\int_\Omega fv=0$, then $f=0$ almost everywhere, right?  In order to answer this we'll need to know what the space of test functions is (that is, which functions are allowed to be $v$?).

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. The question is in n-dimensional Euclidean space, but shouldn't it apply to any measureable space?

Comment: What I mean is, without knowing what kind of functions are allowed to be the function $v$, it's hard to answer the question.  For example, are we allowed to just take $v=f$?  Or is $v$ to be chosen from some smaller class of acceptable functions than $f$ is?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread. The space is $C^\infty(R^n)$ , the space of infinitely differentiable functions.